# How to I convert the following into a list of numbers?

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have the following expression

```
K == 2.7536 || K == 4.6917 || K == 6.3913 || K == 8.3237
```

That I would like to convert into a table or list of numbers that look like the following.

```
{2.7536, 4.6917, 6.3913, 8.3237}
```

Is it possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
expr = K == 2.7536 || K == 4.6917 || K == 6.3913 || K == 8.3237

K /. {ToRules[expr]}
```

Be aware that `K` is a built-in symbol and avoid assigning values to it (otherwise obscure things will get broken).

Answer (score 2):

```
test = k == 2.7536 || k == 4.6917 || k == 6.3913 || k == 8.3237
Cases[test, _ == x_Real -> x]
```

Comment: `Cases[ test, x_Real, 2]` also work

Answer (score 1):

How about the function

```
extractor[arg_] := arg[[All, 2]][[#]] & /@ Range@Length@arg
```

with usage

```
extractor[K == 2.7536 || K == 4.6917 || K == 6.3913 || K == 8.3237]
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation that indexes into the list and then Applies List:

```
stuff = K == 2.7536 || K == 4.6917 || K == 6.3913 || K == 8.3237;
List @@ stuff[[All, 2]]

{2.7536, 4.6917, 6.3913, 8.3237}
```